Error when importing `cairosvg` on Windows
I'm on Windows (Windows 11)
I installed cairosvg using pip:
pip install cairosvg

But when I import it I have this error:
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'

I tried many fixes, including installing GTK+ Runtime:
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\GTK+ Runtime\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'C:\GTK+ Runtime\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1

But there's still errors.

What's your Python version?

@16171413 The last one, Python 3.12.4.

Note that there's a possibility of having compatibility issues with your python version because Python 3.12 was officially released in October 2023, after the stable release of CairoSVG 2.7.1.

So you can downgrade to Python 3.11 and follow the installation procedure in my answer.

I also have Python 3.9.13.

Have you tried with Python 3.9?

I didn't. I will try tomorrow and give you feedback.

You can install CairoSVG 2.7.1 using:
python -m pip install CairoSVG

Ensure you're using a supported Python version. According to the docs:

The current version of CairoSVG requires at least Python 3.6, it doesn’t work with Python 2.x. Older versions of CairoSVG (1.x) work with Python 2.x, but they’re not supported anymore. CairoSVG and its dependencies may require additional tools during the installation: a compiler, Python headers, Cairo, and FFI headers. These tools have different names depending on the OS you are using.

Note that on Windows, you’ll have to install Cairo (with GTK for example) and Visual C++ compiler for Python.

Can you add a link to download Visual C++ compiler for Python?

Sure here you go https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers
